# How to enable the directive "short_open_tag" via the. Htaccess Apache [PHP 5.3]

Tags: php, apache, cgi

I am currently using PHP 5.3.8 and I can not access it with `php.ini`.

I absolutely must enable the PHP directive "short_open_tag" to On it because I work with a great CMS that uses only the `<? ?>`.

I tried to enable it with my Apache .htaccess (`php_value short_open_tag 1`), but adding this causes Apache to always issue 500 errors.

N.B. My server works with PHP in CGI mode.

Comment: Can't be that great a CMS if it uses short tags exclusively.

Comment: `The CGI version of PHP does not read .htaccess.`

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is running as a CGI, then you cannot use a .htaccess file to set PHP flags, this only works if PHP is an Apache module.

You can use [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) to set this flag from a PHP script, but this won't help you since ini_set only affects the currently running PHP process and doesn't persist.

Your only option may be to request your host enable short tags in php.ini, or edit each PHP file to replace `<? with <?php`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use...

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', '1');
```

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (`PHP_INI_ALL`).

Hopefully this great CMS has a front controller where you can replace the first `<?` with `<?php`, and then use `ini_set()`.

Comment: PHP_INI_ALL in PHP 4.0.0. PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP < 5.3.0